# Send 'form-data' as body in Karate framework feature file

Tags: api, automation, karate, ui-automation, feature-file

As part API Automation using karate framework, I am trying to send '**form-data**' as body in karate feature file.

Please provide your solution with following example attached.[image]

I tried to call the get method with body as form-data using karate framework feature file.

**Feature**: Get API
**Background**:

- def data =
  """

  {
  "name":"tom",
  "email":"tom110@gmail.com",
  "gender":"male",
  "status":"active"
  }

  """

**Scenario**: get Auth details
Given url 'https://demo.domain.com/ea80952e/oauth2/token'
And request data
When method GET
Then status 200

Comment: please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -and if you read the documentation, you can save a lot of time: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#form-field

Answer (score 0):

You can use form-data like this:

```
And multipart field client_id = 76t775e676
```